Can you resign a Key Exchange Keyk, or do you have to download an unsigned one and sign it?
Say a system has the manufacturer's Platform Key pre-enrolled, along with the manufacturer's Key Exchange Key. I think the Key Exchange Key had to have been signed by the Platform Key.
As far as I can tell, there is no way for me to get an unsigned copy of the manufacturer's Key Exchange Key.
Is it possible to resign the manufacturer's existing Key Exchange Key with a new Platform Key, or am I stuck with a system locked by the manufacturer?

The Platform Key doesn't sign the KEK; it signs the update operation that inserts a list of KEKs into the respective EFI variable. The signature doesn't become part of a KEK or part of the final list.
Replacing the PK should therefore have no effect on the KEK list.
You can read the EFI variables using Linux efitools' efi-readvar into an .esl ("signature list") file, then use sig-list-to-certs to extract the individual certificates. Either efi-updatevar or sign-efi-sig-list can then be used to prepare a new signed update (which can either replace or append to the list).
(Although I don't think you need the manufacturer's certificate in the KEK list, anyway – you only need it in the db list, for drivers and stuff, but the KEK is only used for applying db/dbx updates which are usually signed either by Microsoft or by yourself. In the Microsoft case, you can find their official EFI certificates on their website.)

(PK, KEK, and 'db' all contain X.509 certificates, which are themselves issued and signed by something – either by a CA or self-signed – but it is a misconception that the KEK certificates must be issued by the PK, or that the 'db' certificates must be issued by a KEK. There is no such relationship, which is indeed why there is a separate KEK list in the first place.
Instead, the KEK and 'db' lists are best thought of as independent "trusted root" or "trusted anchor" lists. Much like with SSL/TLS CAs, once certificates are added to the 'anchor' list, their issuer/signer is irrelevant – the certificate itself becomes a trust root.)

My apprehension with the manufacturer's KEK is that wouldn't it be needed to prevent a firmware update from bricking the system? My understanding is that the manufacturer's firmware update will replace critical system software and the update will not be able to add the new signatures to the db variable without the manufacturer's KEK being in the system.
